# .htaccess redirect from subdirectory to parent directory file but maintain url path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My apologizes if this has been answered but I haven't found anything that works for me. This is on a cheap godaddy shared server, php based.

I have tried a few RewriteRules but to no avail.

Basically, if you are linked to something like :

```
www.example.com/items/apple
```

It would keep that in the url, but instead go to:

```
www.example.com/items
```

In the items page, I would be able to get the /apple part and do with it as I will. Either having it passed in through parameter like ?dir=apple or just as the /apple. My problem right now is the redirecting. My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+) /item?dir=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Does switching the order of your rules help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an additional condition and/or switch the order:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews

RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+) /item?dir=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```